# using a regex wildcard within a specific pattern match

Tags: python, regex

my code:

```
f = open("file.bin", 'rb')
s = f.read()
str1 = ''.join(re.findall( b'\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00(.*?)\x00\x01\x00\x00', s )[0])
```

I have some binary files from which I want to extract information (strings). The information/strings in this file looks like "[DELIMITER]String1[DELIMITER]STRING2"... The delimiters used in these files are always different but the 00's are always the same so a good workaround would be to tell regex that `\x12` and `\x01` can be anything.

So what I would need is

```
str1 = ''.join(re.findall( b'\x00\x00\x00\x[ANYTHING]\x00\x00\x00(.*?)\x00\x[ANYTHING]\x00\x00', s )[0])
```

How can I do this in regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* try

```
str1 = ''.join(re.findall(b'\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00(.*?)\x00.\x00\x00', s)[0], re.S)
```

The `re.S` is needed for `.` to match absolutely any character (or byte in this case), including `\n` (aka `\x0a`).

(Notice that to the regular expression engine, each `\xnn` is just 1 character, so you cannot use any operators within such escape).